# funcall function error cannot take car lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

What's wrong with this code?

```lisp
(defun f (l)
  (funcall #'(lambda (ff)
                (cond
                  ((null l)nil)
                  ((listp (car l)) (append ff (f (cdr l)) (car ff)))
                  (t (list (car l)))))
           (f (car l))))
```

If I enter (f '(( 1 2 3))) it gives me an error:

```lisp
 "Cannot take car of 1".
```

What's wrong?

Comment: you call `(f (car l))` unconditionally and it's result must be ready before your lambda is applied. `(f (car l))` will of course do the same so you end up with `(f (car (car (car (car (car .....))))))` until the arguments is no longer a list in which you'l get the error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a more detailed explanation of the comment of @Sylwester, that answers correctly to the question.

If you write `(f '((1 2 3))` then the function `f` is called, `l` is bound to `((1 2 3))`, and the result is the application of the internal function `(lambda (ff) (cond ...))` to the value of `(f (car l))`.

To perform this application, first `(f (car l))` is evaluated to produce a value, and since `l` is bound to `((1 2 3))`, its `car` is `(1 2 3)`.

So, `f` is applied to the list `(1 2 3)`, which is bound to `l` in the recursive call. This evaluation again means that `f`should apply the internal function `(lambda (ff) (cond ...))` to the value of `(f (car l))`, that is to `(f 1)`.

The process is reapeated, `l` is bound this time to `1`, and again `f`should apply the internal function `(lambda (ff) (cond ...))` to the value of `(f (car l))`, but, since `l` is now `1`, the function tries to evaluate the `(car 1)`, which produces the error that you have found.

Comment: It is not clear to me what is the objective of the function. What are you trying to do? Otherwise I cannot suggest any correction.

Comment: I created function labda ff because for school I had the requirement to propose a solution for the initial code in which the f(car l) to not be call recursively(in the second branch). So for this is lambda function. To call it instead of call f(car l).